# $\operatorname{Proj}k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{k}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes

While dealing with the Proj construction, I encountered with this seemingly-simple question, but somehow I can't get the point at this moment.

> Is the scheme $$\operatorname{Proj}k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$$ isomorphic to the projective line $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{k}$, where $k$ is a field?

I considered the morphism 
$$k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)\to k[x_{0},x_{1}]$$ given by the evaluation $$(x,y,z)\mapsto(x_{0},x_{1},0)$$ and its induced morphism $$\mathbb{P}^{1}_{k}\to \operatorname{Proj}k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$$ which should be well-defined in this case. But I don't know what to do to check this is indeed an isomorphism.

Any help or hint will be appreciated!

Comment: look at the radical of the ideal.

Comment: Taking the radical loses information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: The surjective homomorphism $f^\# : k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2) \to k[x,y]$ (with $z \mapsto 0$) of graded algebras is an isomorphism when localized at $x$, $y$ or $z$ resp. the images.

**More details**: Let $X=\mathrm{Proj} k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$ and let $f : \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ be the closed immersion induced by $f^\#$. Since the graded algebra is generated by $x,y,z$, we have $X=D_+(x) \cup D_+(y) \cup D_+(z)$. Therefore, it suffices to prove that $f^{-1}(D_+(a)) \to D_+(a)$ is an isomorphism for $a \in \{x,y,z\}$. But this precisely means that $$(f^\#)_{(a)} : k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)_{(a)} \to k[x_0,x_1]_{(f^\#(a))}$$
is an isomorphism of rings, where $(a)$ denotes homogeneous localization at the element $a$. In fact, we have an isomorphism on the whole localization  $(f^\#)_a : k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)_{a} \to k[x_0,x_1]_{f^\#(a)}$: For $a=x$ we have $$k[x^{\pm 1},y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)=k[x^{\pm 1},y,z]/(z,yz,z^2) = k[x^{\pm 1},y].$$
For $a=y$ we have
$$k[x,y^{\pm 1},z]/(xz,yz,z^2)=k[x,y^{\pm 1},z]/(xz,z,z^2) = k[x,y^{\pm 1}].$$
For $a=z$ we have
$$k[x,y,z^{\pm 1}]/(xz,yz,z^2)=0=k[x,y]_{f^\#(z)}.$$

**Global solution.** Projective schemes have a beautiful description via their functors of points. $\mathbb{P}^1$ represents the functor which takes a $k$-scheme $T$ to the set of (iso-classes of) tuples $(\mathcal{L},x,y)$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on $T$ and $x,y$ are two global sections of $\mathcal{L}$ which generate $\mathcal{L}$. Also, $X$ represents the functor which takes a $k$-scheme $T$ to the set of tuples $(\mathcal{L},x,y,z)$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on $T$ and $x,y,z$ are two global sections of $\mathcal{L}$ which generate $\mathcal{L}$ and which satisfy the relations $x \otimes z = 0$, $y \otimes z = 0$, $z \otimes z = 0$ (these are global sections of $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes 2}$). Now our task is simply to prove $z=0$! Since $\mathcal{L}$ is invertible, it suffices to prove that $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{L}} \otimes z : \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{L}$ is zero. Since $(x,y,z) : \mathcal{O}_T^3 \to \mathcal{L}$ is an epimorphism, it suffices to prove that the composition $\mathcal{O}_T^3 \to \mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{L}$ is zero. But this is precisely what the relations $x \otimes z = 0$, $y \otimes z = 0$, $z \otimes z = 0$ tell us!

Comment: I think I figured out how to do this: we have to check that the topological part morphism and a sheaf morphism are isomorphisms, and to do that we have to use the principal open sets of the target. Then the problem is reduced to check the localized morphisms are isomorphisms at each homogeneous element, and this is doable (although still I don't know why those three elements are enough).

Comment: There is no need to go into the topological and the sheaf part. But your idea is correct. I have added some details.